# Building private Typescript packages in a monorepo

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx, pnpm, esbuild, pnpm-workspace

How should private (not published) Typescript libraries in a monorepo be built so they can be shared amongst other libraries and apps (both Node and browser) in the repo? I'm using `nx` and `pnpm` to manage the monorepo.

1. Should they each be transpiled to Javascript, or can the consuming package import the Typescript directly?
2. How should their pnpm dependancies be configured (`dependancies`, `peerDependancies`) such that consuming package doesn't need to list these dependancies, but also prevents multiple copies?
3. What module format should be used for private packages used in both Node and browser builds?
4. Do the libraries need to be bundled with `esbuild`/`webpack`/etc?

I realize there are multiple questions, but they all come down to what the build step for the libraries should look like. I am currently trying just `tsc` and `es2020` modules, but am having issues, such as Jest failing to import these libraries in a dependent library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build all the packages together in one step. They can have different tsconfig build configurations though, if you prefer different code styles.

You reference the typescript (as you don't even need to build to JS). Your imports can use the package name as reference `import {Foo} from '@CompanyName/fooLib'` and pnpm workspaces will link them to the right package.

Dependencies should be referenced in package.json without version: `"@CompanyName/fooLib": "*"`as you will only use the most current version of shared libs, unless you do publishing.

The bundling depends on your framework, project size etc. There is also Turbopack, Vite (with and without SWC), so this can't be answered without knowing how much speed or LTS is important for you.

Comment: Thanks, I may have been overthinking this. It seems the Jest issues were due to missing a flag ([`useESM: true`](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/next/guides/esm-support/). It seems `tsc` without bundling is sufficient for private libraries. Will share my full config once I confirm it's working.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Should they each be transpiled to Javascript, or can the consuming package import the Typescript directly?

I'm using `tsc` to build `.js` and `.d.ts` for the library in a `dist/` folder.

> 2. How should their pnpm dependancies be configured (dependancies, peerDependancies) such that consuming package doesn't need to list these dependancies, but also prevents multiple copies?

Simple `dependancies` seem to be working.

> 3. What module format should be used for private packages used in both Node and browser builds?

`type: "module"` in `package.json` is working as long as other tools (Node, Jest, etc.) are configured to expect ESM.

> 4. Do the libraries need to be bundled with esbuild/webpack/etc?

No, the consuming packages can pull in the files they need without bundling.